# ActiveRecord - How to use `around_validation`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm trying to get `around_validation` to work with Rails/AR 3.1.3 - but without success.
If I'm not wrong, acording to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html
it should work by defining the method within the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def around_validation
    puts "jo!"
    yield
  end
end
```

but nothing get executed :-( - What am I doing wrong? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out on my own:

There is no `around_validation`. Instead, overwrite protected `run_validations!`.

-> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no callback `:around_validation` available with Rails 3. So your method is not called. What do you want to do?